# Using 2N7000 with 3.3V signal

Tags: mosfet, avr

I have attached a 2N7000's gate to my AVR chip output pin. I am sending a PWM signal to it.

[image]

I am powering my AVR chip from 3.3V power source so the maximum voltage it can output at G is 3.3V. Then across drain and source is connected my motor which is powered by 6V. Even at maximum G voltage of 3.3V, the voltage across drain and source does not go above 4V. I simply can't understand the relationship between the gate voltage and voltage of the load. Could someone please explain it to me plainly with some examples like what will happen if the motor was powered with 24 volts instead of 6V?

Comment: Good, we have a schematic.Ideally you would also annotate the voltages in the schematic. Now tell us about the load (the motor), how much current does it take. *Even at maximum G voltage of 3.3V, the voltage across drain and source does not go above 4V* Do you even realize that if your circuit was working correctly, when Vgs = 3.3 V then you should have a Vds much **smaller** (not larger) than 4 V. Only when Vgs = 0 would you expect Vds more than 4 V.

Comment: I don't know. all that i know about it that it's rated to work at 6V. If I connect this motor directly to the battery source of 6V, it runs very fast. But though the above schematics it runs much slower. How does current become involved with this?

Comment: @A.Munir Motors require a lot of current, more than most other things encountered in electronics.

Comment: *How does current become involved with this?* The 2N7000 can only switch a current of 200 mA. If your motor draws say 500 mA then the NMOS will break, in an instant. Simple as that. The current is extremely important. So probably you broke your 2N7000. Next time: find what current the motor draws (look in datasheet or measure it) then find a MOSFET that can easily handle that current. Example: if the motor draws 1 A you get a MOSFET that can handle **at least** 2 A. If you can get a 10 A MOSFET: even better, then the MOSFET would not have to work so hard.

Comment: When I try different duty cycles, motor speed does change. It means that the NMOS is responding to different voltage levels at the Gate. It's just a motor I got out of a toy so I don't know the current rating of it. But I do have other motors whose current ratings I am aware of. Even if I replace them with this motor, the speed of motor at maximum duty cycle i.e. 3.3v at Gate is not as fast as if it was connected directly to the power source. So let's say if the current was less than 200 mA what is relation between voltage at Gate and the voltage between Drain and Source

Comment: When you measure the voltage across the FET, you're putting one probe on the drain lead and one on the source (ground), right?

Comment: Yes. And it gives weird readings with and without motor in it. Without motor the voltage doesnt move, no matter what the voltage at gate is. Just constant 5.5. But with motor in it, it keeps fluctuating but usually stays around 4v

Comment: The 2N7000 has a drain-source resistance of 5\$\Omega\$ when it's gate-source voltage is **10V**.  That's way to high to drive anything but a teeny motor.  Add to that, you're only giving it a gate-source voltage of 3.3V, and the answer is that it's not a suitable part for the application.  You need to measure the current on your motor when it's free-running at 6V, then multiply by about five for stall current, then find a FET that'll handle that current *with a gate voltage of 3.3V*.

Comment: You're looking for a "logic level" FET, but you need to be careful because some logic level FETs are only rated for a \$V_{gs}\$ of 5V, not down to 3.3V.  You need to scrutinize the data sheet -- manufacturers don't actually lie, but they do tell the truth in very creative ways.

Comment: This part has a relatively high on resistance (5 ohms) and is not really suitable for most motor drives due to the limited drain current it supports. Given you see about 4V at the drain, then ohm's law gives about 800mA (which is sufficient to fry the internal silicon). Datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You say that 500mA will fry it in an instant, but the 2N7000 is actually rated for 500mA surge current; 200mA is its continuous rating.

Comment: @PeterSmith You're assuming the FET is fully on. The ON datasheet you linked has a worst-case threshold voltage of 3.0V, so it may not be fully on.

Comment: Can I clarify something? Is 2n7000 supposed to be just ON and OFF? I thought like if you give it 1.5V may be it will let a small current pass through drain to source. Amd if you gradually increase the voltage, the current let through would increase. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Hearth That 500 mA surge current can only flow for a very short time: "a surge". Probably that limit is due to heating up of the MOSFET. A 500 mA current during 1 second and then allowing 10 seconds to cool off, is probably already on the limit. For 500 mA you **really** need a more powerful MOSFET.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I was thinking of the startup surge of a motor.

Comment: @A.Munir In this application, it should be either on or off. It doesn't have to be, but you are using it as a switch.

Comment: *I was thinking of the startup surge of a motor* Sure but that surge can kill the "small signal" 2N7000 anyway. Only a very low power motor would be OK-ish. I would then still use a MOSFET with a lower Rdson, like AO3400.

Comment: *..I thought like if you give it 1.5V may be it will let a small current pass through drain to source. Amd if you gradually increase the voltage, the current let through would increase. Or am I wrong?* No you're correct. But **not** with a motor as a load. Use a 1 kohm resistor as a load so that **the current is limited to a safe value**. Then what you write is true. With the motor, the 2N7000 will simply be destroyed.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 7):

The 2N7000 is inappropriate for this application. At a 3.3V Vgs it will only conduct a few mA before the voltage across it may rise unacceptably.

A more appropriate part for switching a small-ish motor might be the [AOD424](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD424.pdf) which is guaranteed to have less than 5.7m\$\Omega\$ Rds(on) with 2.5V drive (at room temperature, it will be considerably more when hot). However, it's only rated at 20V so it can't be counted on to switch a 24V motor.

The 30V-rated [IRFR3708](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfr3708pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356318cc320be) has less than 30m\$\Omega\$ Rds(on) with 2.8V drive (more than 5x worse) and is a fair bit more expensive (around double).

Generally the higher the Vds voltage rating, the less likely you'll be able to find a suitable part that can be driven directly from 3.3V logic, so if you need to drive a relatively high voltage motor you'll want to use a gate drive circuit that gives you 5 or even 10V.

Motors tend to draw quite a bit more current when starting, and that should be taken into account. A 1A motor may draw 10A or more when starting. They can also produce voltage if inertia or something else spins the shaft so your circuit should be designed to not be damaged by that.

Also you should incorporate low voltage lockout (or suitable heat sinking) in your system level design so that it's not possible for the MOSFET to be destroyed if the system power is at some intermediate level that partially turns it on. Obviously that's much more likely if the power source is from batteries, but it's a good idea to consider even mains "brown-out" conditions to make your design bulletproof.

Comment: *The 2N7000 is inappropriate for this application* Indeed, the datasheet does not say: "Small Signal MOSFET" in the title for nothing. Switching power to a motor is not "small signal". Switching a (20 mA) indicator LED on/off, that **is** small signal.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Agreed, but to be fair to a newbie, "small" is relative. Perhaps she or he was thinking "this motor is small compared to some other motor." :)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie There's a tendency to be positive and to look optimistically at datasheet values .. "oh, the motor no-load run current is (say) 75mA and the MOSFET is "rated" for 200mA continuous so it should do".. well, no.  Even with enough drive voltage it's marginal unless the motor is flea size. With 3.3V drive it isn't even good for switching a (blindingly bright) 20mA LED. Maybe a 1 or 2mA LED.

Comment: "..to look optimistically at datasheet values.."  There actually are manufacturers that are what I consider to be honest about their front-page data sheet values -- i.e., if they say 10A, they mean 10A with realistic heat sinking, over temperature.  But I can't tell you *who*, because most mean "10A with perfect heat sinking at 25C", which is, of course, totally unrealistic.

Comment: @TimWescott You mean you don't cool your TO-220 transistors with water from a recirculating chiller? How about the ones that say 300A (or whatever insane number) with an asterisk/footnote that the package limits it to a small fraction of that value?

Answer (score 1):

The lesson to learn here is how to create a design spec just knowing Ohm's Law and load behavior. then choosing parts to meet this criteria.
[image]

### Load behavior

DC Motors have inductance,L and resistance, DCR and can generate voltage (BEMF) with speed [kV/RPM] to reduce the start current, (Is) draw as it reaches full speed with no load. The ability to remove move heat depends on size so a small motor has some ['C/W] rise like any heatsink, but at room temp ambient will have some rated power limit, Pm @ Imax @ Vrate.

What is the DCR of motor? Typically DCR= 10% ( +/-25%) of Vr/Ir=Rr rating where Rr is equivalent full load impedance at about 82% of no load full speed.

**Then switch resistance RdsOn must be << 10% at starting current or <1% of rated full load impedance, Rr.**

**If Vr=5V Ir=1A then Rr= 5 Ohms so RdsOn<1%Rr or 50 mOhms.**

The 2N7000 has abs. max power of 350mW and RdsOn = 5 Ohms which in this example is 100x too large thus temp rise is 100x too great (poof) from I^2R. Also 3.3V is insufficient to drive Vgs. so a Vgs(th) of 1.5Vmax is suggested for Vgs(th)

Answer (score 0):

Mosfet's aren't magical. In this application, running presumably from low voltage, you'd need a much better mosfet... or a cheap medium-power NPN transistor as a switch. Assuming that the motor is 24V, a BD135, BD137 or BD139, and their equivalents, would work fine up to about 1.5A. At 1.5A, the VCE(sat) is <0.3V worst case. The dissipated power during ON state is thus about 0.2W to 0.5W - well within reason for those parts, as long as the part doesn't get too hot.

So, your "conundrum" could be solved with readily available bipolar transistors - if getting a proper mosfet is hard. Everyone who sells electronic components will have some bipolar transistors suitable for this task.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Jd3A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit above uses a switch Q2 in Darlington configuration with Q1.

R1 limits Q1's base current. R2 and R3 limit Q2's base current. R4 discharges the base of Q2 during turn-off. C1 absorbs the AC component of Q2's base current.

R6+C3 snub switching transients on Q2. This snubber should be connected directly across the collector and emitter terminals of the transistor, and the leads of R6 and C3 have to be cut as short as possible.

The exact values of R6 and C3 depend somewhat on motor impedance and PWM frequency and should be adjusted experimentally so that the Q2 collector current switching current spikes are about equal on turn-on and turn-off.

D1 is a free-wheeling diode for the motor's back-EMF, while R5 and C2 quench the diode's switching transients, as well as some of the EMI generated by the motor.

D1, R5 and C2 should be connected directly to the motor terminals, keeping the leads as short as possible.

I'm modeling the motor as a 0.1mH inductor with 24 ohm equivalent series resistance (ESR). You may want to measure the DC resistance and inductance on the motor, to be able to model it.

V1 should be the 3.3V supply used by the MCU. Q1 needs < 100mA from it.

V3 can be essentially any voltage above 1V.

Note that using a Mosfet in place of Q2 will still require a gate drive circuit - likely more than one transistor, or a specialized IC should be used. The snubbers R5-C2, R6-C3 are not optional with the Mosfet either.

To tweak PWM motor drive circuits you'll need motor current sensing, to observe the transients during switching. It can be an AC current probe, or a suitable current transformer plugged in series with Q2's collector, driving a 50 ohm terminated oscilloscope input. The current transformer could be something you could wind yourself on a ferrite core reclaimed from a discarded power supply.