# Motor/MOSFET does not react to input on breadboard

Tags: mosfet, motor, input, thermistor

[image]

I have tried so many different variations on breadboard of this circuit but the motor seems to just be powered by the power rail on the breadboard. It does not react to any change in the input and seems that the whole input is redundant to the MOSFET. (The MOSFET that I am using is WH50 2N7000.)

Essentially, if the thermistor is increased and exceeds the threshold of 25℃, the motor activates. If below the threshold, the motor will not operate. Theoretically it works but on breadboard it does not. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: There is no specific ON/OFF in your circuit. You should read about how MOSFETs work first.

Comment: Theoretically is does not work!

Comment: @Andyaka: that depends on what theory you use!

Comment: That circuit probably comes from yet another "tutorial" site where they don't actually build the damn things, or if they build them but the build doesn't work, they don't believe their own eyes and just assume "we did something wrong"... and publish the thing anyway :( This circuit has no chance of working adequately as shown, not even for the most relaxed specifications that still remain practical (i.e. we don't want "switching" to happen across a temperature variation of 100C).

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is really a bad design and **much too simple** to work properly as it 
will turn on/off the MOSFET only gradually, that is a bad thing as that will cause current to flow through **and** a voltage to be present across the MOSFET. As P = V * I that means Power is dissipated in the MOSFET. Not a good thing. Even worse with an 2N7000 which cannot handle much power.

What is needed is an **abrupt** switch on/off of the MOSFET.

Also the 2N7000 **by far** isn't powerful enough to drive a motor. You should use a MOSFET which has a maximum current rating that is a lot higher than the 2N7000, it can only handle about 200 mA. Much less than what most motors require. Also see [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422475/using-2n7000-with-3-3v-signal).

So probably you have already **damaged** that poor 2N7000. You really need a better circuit.

Here's an example using some CMOS inverters between the resistors and the gate of the MOSFET. As you also don't want the motor switching on/off constantly around the tripping point you should use schmitt-trigger inverters which will add [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

[image: schematic]

For the 2 NOT gates I suggest using the [HEF40106](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF40106B.pdf) IC (or an equivalent one). Connect the inputs of the 4 unused NOT gates (the HEF40106 has 6 NOT gates) to ground.

Comment: Using that gate would make for a very imprecise comparison.  A real comparator would be much more precise.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I will try to find an alternative to the 2N7000 that should be suitable to handle the current and make some changes to the circuit.

Comment: @TimWescott You probably need your comment to better explain what you mean if you want it to be useful. "Precise" can relate to the switching point voltages for a given IC or the data sheet min/typ/max voltages. A given 40106 upper and lower hysteresis points are probably "good enough" in this application and the actual-typical values will usually be closer to the spec sheet typicals than to the spec sheet min/maxs. So ... .

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, this is a "quick and dirty" circuit. A circuit based on an opamp could have more predictable threshold levels but is also a bit more complex and for a beginner not easy to understand let alone dimension properly (getting the resistor ratios correct I mean). So I chose this one which fixes the main issue of the original circuit. Also for "real precise" I'd use the ADC inside a microcontroller.

Comment: It certainly solves the worst problem with the circuit, and as @RussellMcMahon points out, "precise" is in the eye of the beholder.